# What curve is always perpendicular to a constant force under rotation?

Tags: plane-curves

[I have created a [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/YXCE7eSW) link to the system I describe below. It helps a lot in understanding.]

> Assume I have a 2D body whose border is a curve. This body is pivoting
>   about a point $(0,0)$. A constant vertical downward force is applied on
>   such body on the point that is always at the same $x$-coordinate. What
>   is the curve profile, such that the force is always perpendicular to
>   the tangent at every point of application, even when the body rotates?

In the GeoGebra model I have used an ellipse, but obviously this doesn't work. I am only really interested for the angle values between $\pm\frac\pi6$ rad.

Thank you vey much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curve you seek is precisely the [involute of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute#Involute_of_a_circle), as the [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animated_involute_of_circle.gif) on the Wikipedia article should make clear:

[image]

<sup>[Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animated_involute_of_circle.gif) by Wikimedia Commons user "Van helsing", reproduced under [CC-BY-2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/deed.en).</sup>

The perpendicular line at any point on the curve remains at a constant distance to the origin. If you simultaneously rotated the curve in the opposite direction to keep the perpendicular vertical, it would look exactly like your Geogebra sketch.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much.